# linker error Xcode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, xcode5

Can't understand the error.

```
duplicate symbol _currentCount in:
    /Users/selim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iXEN-aimjepotqgbjmlaghqjovwpsngvx/Build/Intermediates/iXEN.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iXEN.build/Objects-normal/i386/Server.o
    /Users/selim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iXEN-aimjepotqgbjmlaghqjovwpsngvx/Build/Intermediates/iXEN.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iXEN.build/Objects-normal/i386/Alerts.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Just check the line where its giving error

Comment: Is currentCount is globle varible? If it is, It seems that you delare it in two files, can you show your code where you declare it.

Comment: Why down vote!!
@underCover developer>> This error does not lead to any line. If it is then I would check it.

Comment: @KudoCC >> Yes. it is. I never got any error like this before.

Comment: it seems like you have declared currentCount multiple time

Comment: I didn't declare it multiple time. Please don't seem I just got a error and post here. I tried my best after that I posted here. Please can anyone explain why I can not declare a variable with same name in two different class? (Without just down voting)?

Comment: @ Mani>> Nice. You can see I am new to stackoverflow. I tried to edit the post but I couldn't because of internet connection. But it gives a down vote again!! :(

Comment: @Rashad you are missing to import any framework to your project

Comment: @Rashad Some body gave down vote for you. But I didn't..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1、if you declare the currentCount in .h file and include it in two .m file.

Add `extern` in front of currentCount declaration in .h file.

example

`extern int currentCount;`

2、if you declare the currentCount in two .m file.

And static in front of currentCount in .m file

example

`static int currentCount`

One more thing, variable declare after @implementation doesn't belong to that class , it is global value.

```
@interface Obj : NSObject
@end

@implementation Obj
int a = 0 ; // a declare in Obj class
@end

@interface Obj2 : NSObject
@end

@implementation Obj2
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init] ;
    if (self) {
        a = 1 ; // you can access it in Obj2 class
    }
    return self ;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it may you write a "#import file.m" instead of "#import file.h". So, In Compiles Resource will duplicate symbol file.o.

You may need to remove the duplicates in Targets **Build Phases** under the **Compiled Sources** grouping.

Comment: I didn't imported .m file. "If more than one class shares a same name this kind of error will come" why? Can please explain?

Comment: "If more than one class shares a same name this kind of error will come"  kehna kya chahte ho @Viruss mca

Comment: @WasimMalek: you can not share same name object of class. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add Quartzcore framework 
or check the file you don't have any duplicate file name in project.i think you add two projects thats why this error is occur.

Comment: I declared a global variable in two different class in server.m and alerts.m file. This give the linker error. I just want to know the reason why I can not do so.